# Change toolbar background color in javafx

Tags: javafx, eclipse-rcp, javafx-css

I have created my application toolbar with **application.e4xmi.**

[image]

And thereafter I tweaked my **.css** as below

```css
/* JavaFX CSS - Main CSS-File */
.root {
-fx-base: rgb(222, 234, 247);
-fx-background: rgb(222, 234, 247);
}
 
.tab {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to top, -fx-base, derive(-fx-base,30%));
}
 
.menu-bar {
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, -fx-base, derive(-fx-base,30%));
}
.tool-bar  > .container{
}
.tool-bar:vertical {
}

.tool-bar:horizontal {
-fx-background: #ececec;
-fx-base: #ececec;
}

.tree-view{
-fx-focus-color: #f21a3f;
}

/*.table-view {
-fx-control-inner-background:  rgb(222, 234, 247);
-fx-table-cell-border-color:derive(-fx-base,+10%);
-fx-table-header-border-color:derive(-fx-base,+20%);
} */
 
.split-pane:horizontal > * > .split-pane-divider {
-fx-control-inner-background : rgb(255, 255, 255);
-fx-border-color: transparent -fx-base transparent -fx-base;
-fx-background-color: transparent, derive(-fx-base,20%);
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 1 0 1;
}
 
.my-gridpane {
-fx-background-color: radial-gradient(radius 100%, derive(-fx-base,20%), derive(-fx-base,-20%));
}
 
.separator-label {
-fx-text-fill: orange;
}
```

Now I am trying to change background color of high-lighted area of toolbar in my eclipse RCP application.

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you use JavaFX `MenuBar`?

Comment: Surely not, most probably it's an `HBox` with `Button`s and `SplitMenuButton`s in it. So please, add a minimal information what you are doing.

Comment: I have created eclipse-rcp toolbar using application.4exmi  file. the flow of the toolbar is :
Application > Trimmed Window > Trim Bar > Tool Bar.

Comment: I tweaked **.root** class from **default.css** file with `-fx-base: rgb(222, 234, 247);
-fx-background: rgb(222, 234, 247);` and now I want to change only high-lighted area of the application.

Comment: I am sure that there is nothing to do with the toolbar classes but I was unable to find any class for trim bar. I think focusing on this particular area can help me out. @DVarga

Comment: Again: please post code.

Comment: Please edit your question and post [mcve] to understand you.

Comment: I have updated Post. @DVarga

Comment: Code updated.@XlintXms

Answer (score 0):

You can use a define a CSS and add this CSS to your product:

```css
.MTrimBar {
    background-color: #000000; 
}
```

Comment: This css class could not make any difference.